# HP Pavilion 15-e015tx Drivers

Tags: drivers

Since i'm new to Linux. So my plan is to explore Ubuntu as my Primary OS, because my secondary OS is Windows 8, Some people were telling me to installing dual boot for Windows 8+Ubuntu but i was thinking to myself this is not a good idea, as it is going to consume a lot space and some resources. So Finally my plan is to get rid of Win 8 and install Ubuntu. But for that i'm gonna need all the drivers and packages right. So where should i get them.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere. Linux does not use vendors drivers mostly: they are either compiled into kernel and provided out of the box, or as a package  for specific item. First install linux, then look what does not work and google for solution.
And do not delete Windows until you are familiar with Linux.